# Making a property decorator type-safe only seems to work on simple classes?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-decorator

So in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYTgJwIZVQHgBVFUAPPMZAZ0QCV0tl8BpAGkTBAFsAjVTAHztmJcqko0qUTDDABzRAB9EVAJ684AGwEAKKNkxzUUAFyJC7ANapVZ5gEpEAbwCwAKESIA9F-MALVEQYLgAHTVQucX1YBEQ4YEQoPxgaUEgYpGQ4VCowAHIoRC5cPEwAOndPH0QAeTBNVSCoGihVEMC0YFkYDKKS-lSsDjgAdwq3AF93dwhNbCoaADE4OGdK719CTEaIP2x5WQUAVkTV7BVpQ8RNGGtEACIAzU04e-XqgE04EDznlVRAklcOY2jkIDIQoURjA-jI5H4oA1EBhQnNZONPAABNAYHB4RAhEA8G4QRA8AyIAC8iCO7imbiAA) I can easily write a property decorator that is type-safe. Meaning that it requires the property its decorating to have a certain type.

Here's the code in case you don't want to check out the playground right now.

```js
function decorate<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends string | symbol>(target: T, key: K) {
  // The implementation of this function doesn't matter.
  // Only its type definition matters for now.
}

class Foo {
  // Try changing 5 to a string like "hello"
  // You'll see that Typescript will rightly complain.
  @decorate public bar = 5
}
```

However when I try implementing that into my actual project, which uses more complicated generics, then it doesn't work anymore. Here's my code:

```js
export const subcollection = <SubModel extends Model, SubModelClass extends Constructable<SubModel>, Target extends Model & Record<Key, SubModel[]>, Key extends string | symbol>(subModelClass: SubModelClass) => (target: Target, key: Key): void => {
  // Again, the implementation doesn't matter.
}
```

I use this decorator in model classes that use Firestore as the backend database. It could look something like this.

```js
class Article {
  @subcollection(Comment) public comments!: Comment[]
}
```

But for some reason, when the types become this complex, I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Article' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Model & Record<string | symbol, Comment[]>'.
```

Type 'Article' is not assignable to type 'Record<string | symbol, Comment[]>'.
Index signature is missing in type 'Article'.

So why does this happen in my real world case, but not in the playground? Am I doing something wrong and could I actually get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that TS can't infer the type of `Key` from the arguments in the second case because you've templated only the factory function and not the function which actually accepts the `key` argument. Because of this TS can't narrow the type for `Key` and that causes it to require an index signature to satisfy `Record<Key, X>`.

The solution is to move the generic parameters for `Key` and `Target` to the inner function so that TS can infer them from the arguments:

```
export const subcollection =
  <SubModel extends Model, SubModelClass extends Constructable<SubModel>> (subModelClass: SubModelClass) =>
    <Target extends Model & Record<Key, SubModel[]>, Key extends string | symbol> (target: Target, key: Key): void => {
      // implementation
}
```